# How does Google Photos handle duplicates?

Tags: google-photos

I've installed Google Photos on my iPhone with the auto-backup feature.

I also have the possibility to install the backup feature on my Mac.

The problem is that iCloud syncs my iPhone pictures with my Mac. So I am afraid if I install Google Photos on my mac I'll have thousands of duplicates.

Is Google Photos smart enough to detect duplicates?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, and a further complication is that the iCloud photo syncing between devices puts highly compressed versions on the non-source device.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Google Photos appear that has a duplicate prevention feature that avoid to create duplicates on uploading time but it's not documented, so proceed carefully.

## Alternatives

Use Picasa instead of Google Photos to backup your Mac photos.

## References

- [Google Photos Help](http://support.google.com/photos)
- [Organize photos in Picasa - Picasa Help](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/156339?hl=en&rd=1)

### Google Photos Help Forum

- [Does google photos automatically not upload duplicates?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/aa3gtHegdOQ)

Comment: It most certainly does and has done since the start that I'm aware of. Try uploading a photo, then uploading the same photo. It will check if the metadata is the same, and if so, will not upload it.